# Hierarchy within one active record table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

I've been banging my head against this for over a day so here we go:

I have a User model. But there are 3 types of user (more actually, but let's get this done). Let's say there is Talent, Managers, and Directors. But they are all users. A manager has many Talents, Talent has one Manager. Director has many Managers, Manager has one Director. Talent has one Director through Manager.

Obviously, with three separate models, this would be trivial. But they are all users and it is necessary to keep them in the User model.

What is the easiest way of doing this? If I have to use a gem, so be it, but I'd rather not...

Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be use case of Single Table Inheritance:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: yes, I see. Thanks. Just to be clear, there is nothing else required at migration for this - just make a user table, then build the classes as described?

Comment: Yup, you'll have just one table `users`, and then you'll add a column `type`, which would help you differentiate the kind of `user` you're creating.

Comment: yep, check out STI

Comment: To be clear that I'm now doing things correctly - when I need, say Talent to belong_to a Manager, I now have to add a manager_id column to the User table right? And then that column just won't be used by Managers, Directors etc... Seems a little messy but that's just what has to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Single Table Inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) is most fitting to your problem description:

> Single table inheritance Active Record allows inheritance by storing
>   the name of the class in a column that by default is named “type” (can
>   be changed by overwriting `Base.inheritance_column`). This means that an
>   inheritance looking like this:
>
> `class Company < ActiveRecord::Base; end`
>
> `class Firm < Company; end`
>
> `class Client < Company; end`
>
> `class PriorityClient < Client; end`
>
> When you do `Firm.create(name: "37signals")`, this record will be saved in
>   the companies table with type = “Firm”. You can then fetch this row
>   again using `Company.where(name: '37signals')`.first and it will return
>   a Firm object.
>
> Be aware that because the type column is an attribute on the record
>   every new subclass will instantly be marked as dirty and the type
>   column will be included in the list of changed attributes on the
>   record. This is different from non Single Table Inheritance(STI)
>   classes:
>
> `Company.new.changed? # => false`
>
> `Firm.new.changed?    # => true`
>
> `Firm.new.changes     # => {"type"=>["","Firm"]}` If you don't have a
>   type column defined in your table, single-table inheritance won't be
>   triggered. In that case, it'll work just like normal subclasses with
>   no special magic for differentiating between them or reloading the
>   right type with find.